# Hibernate 5 migration and entity merge

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, merge

I'm trying to upgrade from hibernate 4.3.10 to hibernate 5.0.12 while using spring boot 1.4.3 and spring 4.3.4. I was able to fix naming issues (at least I hope so) but now I'm stuck at "merging", well, merge doesn't work for some reason. I have this piece of code:

```
DeviceEntity entity = entityManager.find(DeviceEntity.class, device.getId());
GroupEntity groupEntity = entityManager.find(GroupEntity.class, group.getId());

entity.getGroups().add(groupEntity);
groupEntity.getDevices().add(entity);

entityManager.merge(groupEntity);
```

`groupEntity` after find() doesn't contain any devices, then I add device to group. After calling merge nothing is saved. This worked in 4.3.4. Mapping for GroupEntity.devices looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups")
private Set<DeviceEntity> devices = new HashSet<>();
```

Mapping for DeviceEntity.groups looks like this:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="T_DEVICE_GROUPS", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name="DEVICE_ID", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName="id")}
)
private Set<GroupEntity> groups = new HashSet<GroupEntity>();
```

I probably miss `@Cascade` but it was working with hibernate 4.3.10 and it didn't help when I tried to add @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE) to GroupEntity.devices.
Do you have any ideas how to approach this, what to check/recheck? I've read https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc but didn't find anything useful there for me.

application context:

```
<bean id="myEmf" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/spring/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto.value}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">legacy-jpa</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    ....classes....
<validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Service where that code runs is marked as `@Transactional(rollbackFor=someException.java)`

Comment: Have you correctly applied transactions?

Comment: Have you tried `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` on both sides ?

Comment: I've updated question. There's @Transactional. Create operation for that device entity in some other method works.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot... Then why the xml?

Comment: @Babl I've tried (even thought it working with older hibernate) but no luck.

Comment: @M. Deinum older app transformed to spring boot app.

Comment: Post the full service and data access method code, please.